# How does one set the tab width in Komodo Edit?

Tags: tabs, komodoedit

This is a rather simple done in Emacs or [NEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEdit), but I could not find how to setup tab width in Komodo Edit (I use 7.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Komodo has a bug in the setting "Allow file contents to override tab settings". Here is the fix:

Go to: *Preferences* → *Editor* → *Indentation*. From this screen, turn off *"Allow file contents to override tab settings"* as this is very buggy and can cause Komodo to override your settings (hence the need to change the per-file-setting in other people's solutions)

From this screen, check all other tab settings, and check the per-language settings in the drop down.

Now close all files and after reopening them the settings should now take effect permanently. This is a better solution as you will no longer have to go to each file and constantly reset the per-file indent settings.

Comment: This works great! Although the GUI path is a little different in the new version 8.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go to the preferences page.

Depending on your display style - GTK style I think, the plus sign or what it is in front of the entry "editor" might be unvisible.

Either double click on "editor" to show the subtree, click into the free space in front of it (like sinking submarines), or search for indent or tab in the search bar.

There you will find the indentation setup details.