# Cutting indentation width from 4 to 2 in Komodo Edit 10

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I'm now using Komodo Edit 10, and I'm (obviously) a bit new to it.
So, I like an indentation of 2 spaces, and not a tab size of 4, like it is in my editor. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274674/how-does-one-set-the-tab-width-in-komodo-edit) question and tried it out. But in my "Editor" tab in the "Preferences" window, there is no setting for "Indent Width".

What do I do?

*Merci d'avance!*

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for **Edit menu > Preferences > Editor > Indentation: Number of space per indent**.  That is "Indent Width" as you put it.

Also make sure to uncheck **Allow File contents to override Tab and Indentation settings**.

Comment: Nope. Nothing in the "Editor" option.

Comment: There is an arrow to the left of the word "Editor".  It might be hard to see with the dark colour scheme.  Expand that and you will see the **Indentation** section.